# Getting 'object_buttons' actions for an object

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I am trying to build a custom folder listing with quick links to the document actions for the object in the folder.

To load the actions defined for a given object `obj` I do in a browser view for the folder:

```
portal_actions = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_actions')
actions = portal_actions.listActionInfos(object=obj, categories=('object_buttons',))
```

But for some reason `actions` always contains only the *Copy* action. *Delete object*, *Rename* etc are missing. When using the Plone UI with the same user (Manager) I can access all actions for the object I.

Experimentation with new dummy actions has shown that the source of the problem must be the permission and condition checking `listActionInfos` performs. But here I'm stuck... Comparing the evaluation contexts used to check the permissions and condition expressions for the actions revealed no significant differences between the invocations from the browser view and the normal Plone UI for the object.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the source of the problem.

The posted code works just fine, but I've managed to convince Zope's security machinery to use the different, less-privileged role than the actual role for my view. Somehow the construction of a different browser view object in the `__init__` method of the view led to this strange behavior.